# Django REST Framework - How to return 404 error instead of 403

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My API allows access (any request) to certain objects only when a user is authenticated and certain other conditions are satisfied.

```
class SomethingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Something.objects.filter(query_hiding_non_authorized_objects)
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, SomePermission)
```

If a user attempts to view a non-authorized object DRF returns a 403 error, however, this gives away that an object with the requested id exists. How can I return 404 errors in these cases?

Note: I also use a custom queryset to hide non-authorized objects from being listed.

Comment: If you already hide them in get_queryset then just removing the permission will net you a 404 instead.

Comment: Haha, great, problem solved in the easiest way possible, would you mind creating an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure, it's done!

Comment: I actually have the opposite behavior. I use `ModelViewSet`. If I had a permission checking the user is the owner of the object, then it return 403, as expected. But if I narrow the `get_queryset` to only display objects owned, then I have, as expected, a 404 on the `List` retrieval. But also a 404 when trying to access an existing object not owned. On the last one, I'd expect a 403...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already hide them in get_queryset just removing the permission will net you a 404 instead.

edit: you can also override the permission_denied method in your View class to throw another exception, this is the default implementation:

```
def permission_denied(self, request, message=None):
    """ If request is not permitted, determine what kind of exception to raise.
    """
    if request.authenticators and not request.successful_authenticator:
        raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated()
    raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(detail=message)
```

Comment: I noticed a problem with this approach: if the queryset includes an object but the permission restricts what operations you can perform on it, this approach will not work and one would have to, e.g., add the restrictions to the query set method

Comment: See my edit, you can try override the function that handles permission denied

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [custom exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) in this case,

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response.status_code == 403:            
        response.status_code = 404

    return response
```

In settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 
'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

**Second Method**

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException


class CustomForbidden(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND


class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not_allowed:
            raise CustomForbidden
```