# Respond with Not Found if user is not authorised to view the instance

Tags: django, permissions, httpresponse

How can I modify Django behaviour, for *some* models only, to obscure the existence of any objects in that model but the ones the user is authorised to view?

By default, Django will respond to a query for a *nonexistent* object with 404 `Not Found`, and to an *existing* object that the user is not permitted to view, with 403 `Forbidden`.

This applies to typical Django views, and specialised views (like Django REST framwork). This is all correct, as a default.

What I'd like to do though, is to present some specific models to each user as containing *only the records that user may view*, and nothing else exists in there to be queried. If they're authorised to view the instance, it is shown; if it exists but they're not authorised, then Django should not reveal even whether that instance exists and should respond only with 404 `Not Found`.

This requirement is **only for *some* models in the database**. For example, confidential documents: the visitor should not be able to sniff around and discover which documents exist and which do not. Either they have permission to view that document, or they should not be told there's anything there just as if they queried a nonexistent document.

For **other models, the normal behaviour is correct** (404 if not found, 403 if it exists but the current user is not authorised).

So, a solution which overrides the exception behaviour globally is not correct for this question.

How can I convince Django to treat specific models as “unauthorised access looks like nonexistent instance”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST Framework - How to return 404 error instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903357/django-rest-framework-how-to-return-404-error-instead-of-403)

Comment: Partly, I think. Can you make an answer to this question, which *specifically* addresses that this behaviour should apply only to certain models and not all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Django's permission system includes [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin), a mix-in class for views which will check the user has a specified permission and handle the cases where they don't.

Because `PermissionRequiredMixin` is a subclass of `AccessMixin`, perhaps a new specific mix-in class can be made that overrides [`AccessMixin.handle_no_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.handle_no_permission):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class PermissionRequiredOrDoesNotExistMixin(PermissionRequiredMixin):
    """ A mix-in class that handles “not permitted” as though it were “not found”. """

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The third-party library [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/) implements a customised [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.mixins.html#permissionrequiredmixin) for views (this class is subclassed from `django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin`).

That custom class has `return_403` and `return_404` attributes, to specify the view should return one of those HTTP responses (instead of the default behaviour to redirect to a login page) when the user does not have the required permission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or:

```
from django.views import View 
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import Http404


class StaffRequired(UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        raise Http404


class HiddenView(StaffRequired, View):
    pass
```